# PHP substr function does not parse properly in foreach

Tags: php, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

I have some files containing the similar formats as follows:

> ```
> Nearest Location:
> 771 km S 43° E of Quezon City
> 051 km S 66° E of Surigao City 
> 007 km S 51° W of Socorro (Surigao Del Norte)
> 049 km N 70° E of PFZ EAST MINDANAO SEGMENT
> ```

What I did was to load each file through `file_get_contents()` and `explode("\n",...)`. So I used `foreach($rows_location as $row_location)` and stored it to `$content_location = $row_location;`. I separated it into 2 parts, the distance and bearing info, and the location neglecting the first line which is as follows:

```
$distance_bearing = substr($content_location,0,18);
$location = substr($content_location, 18);
```

but the problem is that it only works for the first row so i saved them separately and got

```
771 km S 43° E of
```

for `$distance_bearing` and

```
Quezon City
051 km S 66° E of Surigao City 
007 km S 51° W of Socorro (Surigao Del Norte)
049 km N 70° E of PFZ EAST MINDANAO SEGMENT
```

for `$location`.

I tried converting each row to `utf8_decode` as it contains a degree symbol and it just returned the same but with the degree replaced with `?`. I also checked `$content_location` if it stores the rows properly and got:

```
Nearest Location:
771 km S 43° E of Quezon City
051 km S 66° E of Surigao City 
007 km S 51° W of Socorro (Surigao Del Norte)
049 km N 70° E of PFZ EAST MINDANAO SEGMENT
```

so I guess it stores it correctly.

I don't know what the problem is, so any ideas will help. Thank you in advance for the help.

---

Sorry guys, I forgot to put the desired output it should be:

```
771 km S 43° E of
051 km S 66° E of
007 km S 51° W of
049 km N 70° E of
```

for `$distance_bearing` and

```
Quezon City
Surigao City 
Socorro (Surigao Del Norte)
PFZ EAST MINDANAO SEGMENT
```

for `$location`.
Thanks again!

Comment: substr() only extracts 18 characters in what you have, was that what you wanted?

Comment: thanks for the input guys, I did some editing to the question for clarification

Comment: It looks like it is only recognizing the eol/`\n` after `Quezon City`, and not after the the other locations.

Comment: Thanks @Sean. Yeah I thought so too so I checked $content_location by printing it and it returns it row by row. That's why I'm confused why it cannot parse even though it explodes it properly.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa, yeah I do want to keep it

Comment: can you show your actual code? the simplified code you reference is working here - https://3v4l.org/9eMOv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_match_all()` will handle the block of text simply.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RVh0Q))

```
$string='Nearest Location:
771 km S 43° E of Quezon City
051 km S 66° E of Surigao City
007 km S 51° W of Socorro (Surigao Del Norte)
049 km N 70° E of PFZ EAST MINDANAO SEGMENT';

if(preg_match_all('/^(.*? of) \K.+/m',$string,$out)){
    list($location,$distance_bearing)=$out;
}
var_export($distance_bearing);
echo "\n\n";
var_export($location);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '771 km S 43° E of',
  1 => '051 km S 66° E of',
  2 => '007 km S 51° W of',
  3 => '049 km N 70° E of',
)

array (
  0 => 'Quezon City',
  1 => 'Surigao City',
  2 => 'Socorro (Surigao Del Norte)',
  3 => 'PFZ EAST MINDANAO SEGMENT',
)
```

Pattern Explanation:

```
/         # start the pattern
^         # match from the start of the line
(.*? of)  # match the leading text upto and including the first occurrence of `of`
 \K.+     # match 1 space, then restart the fullstring match using \K then match the rest of the string
/         # end the pattern
m         # force ^ character to match every line start instead of string start
```

Comment: Great explanation! You can also utilize pattern name matching `preg_match_all('/^(?P<distance_bearing>.*? of) \K(?P<location>.+)/m',$string,$out)` Which will give `$out` an associative index for the pattern names. `$out['location']` and `$out['distance_bearing']` like so: https://3v4l.org/jC5SK

Comment: Yes, I think that it is a good option for this task.  I generally stay away from named capture groups because you also get the indexed subarrays too, which means output array bloat.  But I will grant you, it saves a function call `list()`.  See the [bloat](https://3v4l.org/uGYc3) -- 5 subarrays versus 2.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa, I tried it with the files that I have, the arrays output the same thing. It parses well with the first line but the rest prints as a whole line as follows: 

771 km S 43РE of "\n"
Quezon City "\n"
051 km S 66РE of Surigao City "\n" 
007 km S 51РW of Socorro (Surigao Del Norte) "\n"
049 km N 70РE of PFZ EAST MINDANAO SEGMENT

Do you think it's an eof thing?

Comment: @phiv can you provide a source file?

Comment: um... maybe give us a var_dump or something, so we can count string length and prove there are invisible characters.  I have another (more convoluted method) if that doesn't display anything.

Comment: @mickmackusa here it is, thanks. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EOv_1YLlrlzRzc_sCzaon19wnU57HfSs

Comment: I was having issues when I first copy pasted your input.  You've got unicode control characters hiding in there...  Use this pattern: `/^(.*? of) \K.+(?=[\pZ\pC]+$)/mu`  See what my unicode metacharacters are standing for: [Whitespace Characters & Control Characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: @phiv yea, your file uses `LF` after `Nearest Location` and `CR` after each location. Along with the unicode metacharacters. See: [image](https://i.imgur.com/OHVuve1.png)

Comment: thanks, @fyrye may I know what you used to display the eof?

Comment: Notepad++, `View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters`. Can also convert encodings and EOLs. Most other IDEs have similar functions, such as PHPStorm which I normally use.

Comment: How about `/^(.*? of) \K.+(?=\s*$)/m` then?  (make the `\s` zero or more)  https://regex101.com/r/dwqaYp/2

Comment: @mickmackusa it returns the same output with only the first line working

Comment: Please show your code block.  `preg_match` or `preg_match_all()`?  (me thinks you are using `preg_match()`)

Comment: @mickmackusa, yup, I am using preg_match_all(), it maybe because only the nearest location end in LF and the rest is CR, i'm currently trying to convert the EOL

Comment: I expect that this should work: `if(preg_match_all('/^(.*? of) \K\S+(?: \S+)*/m',$string,$out)){`

Comment: I am able to reproduce using `file_get_contents` See output: [image](https://i.imgur.com/uzjhhbA.png) of the initial answer. Your latest pattern breaks into an array of 3 strings.

Comment: @phiv Use this `$string = utf8_encode(str_replace("\r", "\n", $string));` Then perform the original answer `preg_match_all`

Comment: Here is the anchor-free version: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a47aeb7ca299d9255637d3f77adbb97ff9b65df2  `/(\d+ km [NESW] \d+° [NESW] of) \K[^\r\n]+/`

Comment: @mickmackusa I get empty values with the `[NESW]` pattern and `file_get_contents` I believe that it is an encoding issue with the source file and the `default_charset` in PHP. When I convert the file to UTF-8 without BOM or use the snippet  I provided on the file contents, the issue goes away with your initial answer.

Comment: ...this has been a hairy one.

Comment: @fyrye, thank you so much, it solved the EOL issue and the code ran :D

Comment: @mickmackusa, thank you so much, by applying the EOL your code works like a charm :D

Comment: thanks fyrye and mickmackusa, you both are life savers!